# I'm getting FOUC on svelte/sveltekit. What can I do? Seeking a solution better than my "onMount" solution

Tags: html, css, svelte, sveltekit

There isn't much on the web about FOUC in sveltekit. Because it's new.

[SvelteKit split second unstyled html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67024130/sveltekit-split-second-unstyled-html)

[Flash of unstyled content in dev mode](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/915)

[FOUC happening in production when using __layout.reset.svelte](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2349)

i am getting the problem in production. I use an AWS EC2 instance, free tier. Could it be that the free tier is slow? People say on the web that FOUC *shouldn't* happen in prod.

Could it be that I have unrealistic expectations? I want *precisely zero* FOUC.

I might use [How to get rid of the Flash Of Unstyled Content](https://medium.com/@fbnlsr/how-to-get-rid-of-the-flash-of-unstyled-content-d6b79bf5d75f) which says basically, "Hide everything, then when you detect the page is fully loaded, unhide it."

[some time later] yeah OK, the previous blog post works, but **is there any better way?** I saw a site with the css put directly in the head of the html, meaning it *couldnt* load without the css, or almost. I was able to make it display for a split second. IMO this solution is "good enough" but **can I do better?**

Here's the code for anyone who has FOUC in Svelte:

app.html:

```
<body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover" class="bg-azure" style="visibility: hidden">
    <div style="display: contents">%sveltekit.body%</div>
</body>
```

The "visibility: hidden: part is the crucial part.

Then in whatever page you want to rid yourself of FOUC on:

```
 onMount(() => {
    document.body.style.visibility = 'visible' // erases 'hidden', replaces with 'visible'
  })
```

Note this only has been tested on small, small sites, that load nigh instantly. I get these values doing a hard reload (dump the cache first) in Chrome: `DOMContentLoaded: 420 ms || Load: 1.16 s`

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing your own CSS or are you using a component library/css framework?

I was facing the same issue, even in production, first thing i did was changing *sveltekit.config.js*, to enable precompression when building:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node'; // using node adapter
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            precompress: true // default is false per documentation
        })
    }
};

export default config;
```

What really fixed for me was ensuring that my components were being server-side rendered, i am using **svelteui** so what i did was, i created a **hooks.server.ts** file in src/ folder and i added:

```
import { prepareStylesSSR } from '@svelteuidev/core';

export const handle = prepareStylesSSR;
```

After that no more FOUC.

More on [hooks](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks).

Comment: The hook worked like a charm for me, thanks!  I was seeing FOUC in dev mode.